# Understanding 8b10b

Tags: serial

I am trying to develop a serial link with 8b10b protocol.
As per my understanding after every conversion I need to send a comma character to identify frame boundary.

If things are done in this way then in every 20 bits , 10 bits will belong to comma characters and 10 bits will be data with 2 bit overhead.
Does it mean that my channel utilization is only 8/20 = 40%. If this is true then why 8b10b is used so frequently.

I am difficulty in understanding the implementation of 8b10b encoder and decoder. How are the framing and deframing done in this coding scheme are there any alternatives to frame and deframe the data in parallel to serial link conversions?
Pls let me know if I am not clear on any point.

Comment: I have no idea where you have that idea with the commas from, are you actually referring to stop bits?

Comment: A frame is normally hundreds or thousands of symbols, not just a single symbol. If you only need to send one byte at a time, there are better choices for encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it sounds like you're like at a technology you don't understand very well. First, find the following IBM white paper on the internet and read it all:

A DC-Balanced, Partitioned-Block, 8B/10B Transmission Code
  A. X. WidmerP. A. Franaszek

It explains that 8b/10b encoding allows enough DC-balanced sets of patterns to encode the values 0..255 and 12 'special characters', named as Knn.m where n and m are different numbers.

Some patterns are designated 'commas', as you talk about. These are typically used to reliably synchronise the link. They are most often inserted as padding between communicated data frames so the receiver does not have long before it can resync' if it loses it.

As the IBM WP says: "To be useful, the comma sequence must be singular and must occur with a uniform alignment relative to the byte boundaries. In the absence of errors, the comma must not occur in any other bit positions, neither within characters nor through overlap between characters."

Of the 12 special characters, three meet these requirements: K.28.1, K.28.5 and K.28.7.

So you don't send a comma every other byte. Special characters are put as as idles between communication frames and commas are the best choice becuase of the guaranteed resync if received bit quality is good enough.

Have a read of the PCI Express spec'. Although 8b/10b encoding isn't used in more recent PCIe versions, it is used in v1.x and more and the spec' will describe all this in good detail. It'll give you a practical example of proper use of 8b/10b. (8b/10b's also used in one of the Ethernets and all sorts but PCIe will do fine here.)

Incidentally, it is a fact of 8b/10b that you only get 80 % of your usable bit rate for data, before you look at what you lose through special characters between frames and all sorts. But the benefits of synchronisation, DC balance and ability to transformer-couple outweight this loss for many applications.

Comment: @TonyM I understand now clearly the usage of comma  characters. But suppose I want to transmit 8 bit wide parallel data serially , how to control the receiver and know that a new frame is present. How can one develop serializer and deserialize

Comment: @Falcon98, you're taking a big jump from 'how does 8b/10b work' to 'how do I design a serial communications system'. That's a completely different question and we nothing about what you have or what you're trying to do. Recommend you create a new question with lots of detail. Lots.